# jquery - how to show a hidden div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a google map embedded in my page whose visiblity is set to hidden. Using a button i want to show the map on the page. Should be done using jquery.

my code - (not working)

```
<div id="map" style="height: 350px; border: 1px solid #979797;visibility="hidden";></div>
```

Anyone can help me with the related jquery codes?

Comment: Have you tried looking on the [jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)?

Comment: It seems that you have wrong style typo syntax. it should be `<div id="map" style="height: 350px; border: 1px solid #979797;visibility:hidden"></div>`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try

```
$('#map').css('visibility','visible');
```

Actually, if style has `display:none`, you can use jquery function

```
$('#map').show();
```

Comment: i have a button 
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="show"/>

and here is my jquery:

$(document).ready(function(){
 

 
    $('#show').click(function(){
     $('#map').show();
    });
 
});

it does not work, could you help me

Comment: @devilived if your style uses 'visibility' it has to be `$('#map').css('visibility','visible');`. Because `$('#map').show();` works for style with `display:none`

Comment: @devilived Your jquery function has to be like this to see how it works. $(document).ready(function(){ $('#show').click(function(){ $('#map').css('visibility','visible');return false; }); });

Comment: I've had to look this answer up every time I try and do this... going back and forth. +1 for the "Why" as this really helps in knowing which to use in which circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

Your style="" tag is also incorrect.  You should have this: visibility: hidden;

Try this:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 350px; border: 1px solid #979797; display: none";></div>

$("#map").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/GhMbU/

`$('div#map').css('visibility', 'visible')`

Answer (score 0):

But `visibility:hidden` is better than `display:none` if you want
to use jQuery to hide it. Because jQuery's `.show()` function overlays some of the page elements like anchor tags, preventing click events.