# how to disable & enable google map on button click in java-script/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**i want to show google map to my user on web page** , *but it should be disable for user interaction initially, when he click a button map become enable and he/she can interact with the map.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fJdtY/2/ check here also.

Comment: Do you want us to write a code for you? You really have to show what you have written/tried until now.

Comment: i want to know about the way to done this task

Answer (score 1):

```
var showMap = $('#show-map');

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    zoom: 8
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#show-map').on('click',initialize)
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwinkelman/gabkawys/)

Comment: i want to show map but in disable state, after button click it becomes enable

Comment: You can put a static image for temporary disable or you can use some text like that "click here to enable map" its a better idea. http://fiddle.jshell.net/cancerian73/T7jLf/20/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=T7jLf

Comment: Or follow this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064275/how-to-deal-with-google-map-inside-of-a-hidden-div-updated-picture

Comment: Or you can disable this div using jquery.

Comment: actually i am showing a location on map to user , if he want to change the location he press edit button map becomes enable and change the location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721552/jquery-how-to-show-a-hidden-div